# Square Modular Summation

Tags: summation, modular-arithmetic, square-numbers

I have been working on modular arithmetic, I have tried to find the summation
$\sum_{i=1}^N N\pmod {i^2}$  without actual calculation   i.e. a shorthand notation or value of this summation for any such $N$.

I have tried to reduce it to $O(\sqrt  N)$

How to solve these problems? How to calculate this value faster in $O(1)$   or $O(\log(N))$?

Is there any sequence?

$S(N) = \sum_{i=1}^N N\pmod {i^2}$

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! What do you denote `%i`?

Comment: Yes, % is shorthand form of MOD

Comment: That's a computer shorthand, I guess? That being said, you consider a sum modulo the (square of the) summation index  which is a dumb variable?

Comment: Yes, I use them regularly. Got used to it